# How to detect M7 co-processor sensoring in an application

Tags: core-motion, uiaccelerometer, apple-m7

I just wanted to make clear. I am using accelerometer in my app, So do we need to add any other framework or method to receive iPhone5s's M7 co-processor data? Is that enough of using **CoreMotion framework** with Method

```
-(void)startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue withHandler:(CMAccelerometerHandler)handler;
```

to receive data from M7 co-processor?Or am I need to include any extra method or framework to get data in iPhone 5s?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M7):

> The Apple M7 and M8 co-processors collect, process, and store sensor
>   data even if the device is asleep, and applications can retrieve data
>   when the device is powered up again. This reduces power draw of the
>   device and saves battery life.

So you don't need to add any other framework.

You can detect the M7 equipped device using `[CMMotionActivityManager isActivityAvailable]` - check the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionActivityManager_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMMotionActivityManager).